Am I on the right path for surjective and injective?
I am learning about discrete and trying to prove f and g are surjective and injective. I think I am on the right path, but my wording does seem very messy.
If f and g are surjective, then so is g ◦ f

Let y be an arbitrary element in the codomain of g ◦ f.

Since  g  is surjective, for each y there exists an element  z
such that g(z) = y. Similarly, since f   is surjective, there
exists an element x in the domain of f such that f(x) = z.

This means (g ◦ f)(x) = g(f(x)) = g(z) = y.

Which means for any y, there exists an x in g ◦ f such that (g ◦ f)(x) = y. Therefore, g ◦ f is surjective.


If f and g are injective, then so is g ◦ f

If (g ◦ f)(x1) = (g ◦ f)(x2), then x1 = x2

Given (g ◦ f)(x1) = (g ◦ f)(x2), we have g(f(x1)) = g(f(x2)).

Since g is injective, if g(u) = g(v), then u = v for any u and v in the domain of g

So f(x1) = f(x2)

Now since f is injective, if f(a) = f(b) then a = b for any a and b in the domain of f.

Therefore, (x1) = (x2)



In your first bullet point of the second proof, you are stating what you want to prove.  You need to show that if $(g \circ f)(x_1) = (g \circ f)(x_2)$, then $x_1 = x_2$.

The first proof looks correct, but it would be much easier to read if you named the domains and codomains (say $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon B\to C$) and always wrote down which set the elements $x,y,z$ are being drawn from. As a minor additional style point, it's helpful if you preserve alphabeticity of parallel sequences of objects—so have $x\in A$, $y\in B$, and $z\in C$ rather than $x\in A$, $z\in B$, $y\in C$.
